# Pipe output of grep to a variable

Tags: terminal, bash, script, command-line

I need to be able to write whether the test for a grep is either **TRUE** or **FALSE** to a variable so I can use it later

For the following, if I run

```
defaults read com.apple.Finder | grep "AppleShowAllFiles"
```

on my system, it would return

```
AppleShowAllFiles = FALSE;
```

Cool. So now I want to pipe this response to a test of some kind. This is where I get stuck.

I think if I can pipe/assign this output to a specified variable, I would be able to run a test on it. Now, just say, I've assigned  the value of this output to a variable, in this case I will use `$ASAF` as my variable, I can run it in a test like this

```
if [ $ASAF = "AppleShowAllFiles = TRUE;" ]; then  
    defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE  
    killall Finder  
else  
    defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles True  
    killall Finder  
fi
```

If there is some other way to do this, I would be more than open to options. I've not had to do something like this for a while, and I'm a bit stumped. I searcehd Google a bit, but it was all answers without explanations and using the return value of `0` or `1`. I think the returned output being assigned to a variable would be more appropriate, as then I can use it over and over in the script as need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `grep` at all:

```
[[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 0 ]] && bool=true || bool=false
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool $bool
osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
```

`defaults read` prints boolean values as `1` or `0`. For example `True` or `YES` as a string is also interpreted as a boolean value, but `-bool true` specifies the value to be actually boolean.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Using the `TRUE` or `FALSE` values of a response. Even better than `grep` to test. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if [[ $(defaults read com.apple.Finder | grep "AppleShowAllFiles") == "AppleShowAllFiles = TRUE;" ]]; then
    defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
else
    defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles True
fi
killall Finder
```

`$(...)` executes the part between `()`and replaces it with the result. So you could also do

```
ASAF=$(defaults read com.apple.Finder | grep "AppleShowAllFiles")
```

to assign the result to `$ASAF`.

PS: I also changed two other things in your script

- use `[[` for the test part (has more functionality than `[` and is builtin in bash
- use `==` to compare strings (`=` is for assignments only`)

Comment: I'm looking at your edit of my post. How did you get the lines that start with `defaults write.com.apple` to indent further than the lines above and below? I tried to get that to work for formatting value, and it failed. :-/

Comment: `>` is for quoting, 4 space characters are for code :-)

Comment: I found that I can assign the output directly to a variable when I invoke it using `foofoo=$(defaults read com.apple.foobar | grep "foo")`. I shall use your method in future. It seems more stable.

Comment: `=` can also be used for comparisons inside `[[` and `[`/`test` in bash. POSIX defines `=` but not `==` (but POSIX doesn't define `[[` either).